# c++ winhttp post request php

Tags: php, c++

i need to know how to overgive parameters from HttpsWebRequestPost function to my php script.

```
LPCWSTR additionalHeaders = L"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
DWORD headersLength = -1;

string HttpsWebRequestPost(string domain, string url, string dat)
{
    //Extra
    LPSTR  data = const_cast<char *>(dat.c_str());;
    DWORD data_len = strlen(data);


    wstring sdomain = get_utf16(domain, CP_UTF8);
    wstring surl = get_utf16(url, CP_UTF8);
    string response;

    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
    LPSTR pszOutBuffer;
    BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
    HINTERNET  hSession = NULL,
        hConnect = NULL,
        hRequest = NULL;

    // Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
    hSession = WinHttpOpen(L"WinHTTP Example/1.0",
        WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

    // Specify an HTTP server.
    if (hSession)
        hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, sdomain.c_str(),
            INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0);

    // Create an HTTP request handle.
    if (hConnect)
        hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"POST", surl.c_str(),
            NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
            WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
            0);

    // Send a request.
    if (hRequest)
        bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest,
            additionalHeaders,
            headersLength,
            (LPVOID)data,
            data_len,
            data_len,
            0);

    // End the request.
    if (bResults)
        bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL);

    // Keep checking for data until there is nothing left.
    if (bResults)
    {
        do
        {
            // Check for available data.
            dwSize = 0;
            if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize))
                printf("Error %u in WinHttpQueryDataAvailable.\n",
                    GetLastError());

            // Allocate space for the buffer.
            pszOutBuffer = new char[dwSize + 1];
            if (!pszOutBuffer)
            {
                printf("Out of memory\n");
                dwSize = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                // Read the data.
                ZeroMemory(pszOutBuffer, dwSize + 1);

                if (!WinHttpReadData(hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer,
                    dwSize, &dwDownloaded))
                    printf("Error %u in WinHttpReadData.\n", GetLastError());
                else
                    //printf("%s", pszOutBuffer);
                    response = response + string(pszOutBuffer);
                // Free the memory allocated to the buffer.
                delete[] pszOutBuffer;
            }
        } while (dwSize > 0);
    }

    // Report any errors.
    if (!bResults)
        printf("Error %d has occurred.\n", GetLastError());

    // Close any open handles.
    if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
    if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    if (hSession) WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);

    return response;

}
```

and the c++ code:

```
int main()
{ 
    printf("%s", HttpsWebRequestPost("mywebspaceaddr", "test.php", "value=1000").c_str());
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

my php looks like this simple:

```
<?php

$val = $_GET['value'];
echo 'value given:' . $val;
?>
```

i recieve only the "value given:" text on console, but no value.

did anyone know how to display the value that was given by the function?

sry for my bad php knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

Your $_GET should be $_POST.
pretty easy, huh?